# Exporting tiled raster assets within mask feature selection?

Tags: qgis, raster, features, global-mapper

I'm familiar with a method of exporting everything within a selected feature within Global Mapper using - Export > Export Raster/Image Format.

This takes everything within that feature and exports to a single image even though the project contains a collection of tiled rasters (sat images)

[image]

However I really want to learn how to do the same operation within QGIS - but I'm struggling as the only feature I can see that comes close is - Raster > Extraction > Clipper

But the 'Input file' selection makes you pick a specific raster - rather than everything? I would prefer not to have to merge the tiled rasters as I've noticed some degradation of quality, and due to the total size of rasters - memory becomes an issue with the processing of merging.

Is there anything I'm missing re exporting entire raster contents within a selected feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found an option that works using QGIS 3.2.0.

- Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster
- Create a Shapefile - making sure it's same CRS as virtual raster.
- Create square feature using advanced Digitizing panel.
- Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster by Mask Layer (selecting virtual raster output as the input for clipper).

`gdalwarp` then, does its thing giving the me option to export to a .tif or .bmp.